# Update media_player.js for Default/Styled media receiver

Tags: chromecast

Is there a way to manually update the version of media_player.js that the Default or Styled media receiver is using?

It appears that it is using v0.3, however, there are a few issues regarding HLS playback that seem to have been fixed with v0.5+. I have confirmed the fixes using media_player.js v0.5, but would like to use the Styled Media receiver for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for bringing that to our attention. We'll update that soon and will try to keep that updated moving forward, that has fallen through the cracks unfortunately.

To answer your original question, there is no way for you to do that :-(